# Disable sudo for a single command in a sh file on macOS Sierra

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sh, sudo

I have been looking everywhere for something to disable sudo access for this one command while maintaining sudo for the rest for the script. **The script is called using sudo e.g. "sudo ./install.sh"**. The snippet in question is this (I currently was trying to make a new user to call the command, but to no use):

```
echo >&2 "Installing Homebrew"
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I only want line 2's command to run as not root/ no sudo. I am very much a noob, so any guidance/alternative methods not including making a new user, would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why not just remove `sudo -u USERNAME` from line 4?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, but the script is run using sudo so every line is sudo. And Homebrew's install script forbids sudo installation.

Comment: Consider how much of the script actually *needs* `sudo`, and whether it would be more appropriate to use `sudo` *in* the script where necessary rather than running the entire script with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

If the script was run with `sudo`, then you can use `$SUDO_USER` to get the original username:

```
echo >&2 "Installing Homebrew"
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

(And don't use `sudo` on the other commands in the script -- if the script itself is run with `sudo`, that's completely redundant.)

BTW, this will fail completely if the script was not run with `sudo` -- for example, if someone logs in as root and runs it, uses `su` to switch to root and run it, etc. It might be better to check first, something like this:

```
if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Installing Homebrew"
    sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
else
    echo "No original user found to install Homebrew under" >&2
fi
```